# PayPal TLS Test URL - PHP curl SSL protocol error

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal

I'm trying to test against a new PayPal test endpoint: `https://tlstest.paypal.com`.

See the very bottom of this page: [TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1 Upgrade Microsite](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1914&viewlocale=en_EN) (Verify your...).

I'm using PHP (5.3.28) and curl (7.30.0 - OpenSSL/0.9.8y - libssh2/1.4.2) on Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://tlstest.paypal.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6); // CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo 'result = '.$result.'<br>';
echo 'errno = '.curl_errno($ch).'<br>';
echo 'error = '.curl_error($ch).'<br>';
curl_close($ch);
```

I'm getting this error:

> 35 Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to tlstest.paypal.com:443

I found this: [Github - Unknown SSL protocol error](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/484) in which someone says:

> Openssl must be at 1.0.1 or higher for TLS 1.2.

Is this correct..?

My PHP OpenSSL is on version: `OpenSSL/0.9.8y` (from `phpinfo()`).

If you do need OpenSSL 1.0.1 or higher to use TLS 1.2 then presumably **every server running PHP with a lesser OpenSSL version** (I'm guessing that's a lot!) will be unable to use any PayPal API's or the PayPal IPN soon.

How do I update my PHP OpenSSL version on Windows..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this working now. It seems as though at least OpenSSL/1.0.1i **is** required for TLS 1.2.

I upgraded my PHP version to 5.6.0, which upgraded OpenSSL to version 1.0.1.

I also needed these:

1. Use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);` to verify the certificate. The default is `true` as of cURL 7.10.
2. Save **cacert.pem** from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html locally (in my case to c:\cert), then update the PHP ini that you're using to reference `cacert.pem` [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35059828/1003183). Using the ini file saves you having to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '\cacert.pem');` in every call.

Comment: After upgrading to PHP 5.6, did the SSL handshake complete successfully without specifying an SSL version yourself? And did you update your curl version as well, or is that still 7.30?

Comment: I left the SSL version in, so not sure if it works without it, might try that soon... cURL verson is now 7.36.0, which seems to come with PHP 5.6.0.